# How does puppet decide if a node is active? (Changed)

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to change default behavior in puppet when a Notify resource is applied to a node. Current state (puppet version 3.8) is that whenever the client is applying a simply Notify message, the client will send a report with state "Active". This is somewhat misleading because nothing really changed on the node.

Is it possible to change this so that puppet will not make a Notify resource change node status to "Active"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`notify` is a special resource, meant to cause an internal class notification, like a changing service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with 'warning' or 'notice' is that the messages are registered at the puppetmaster log, as opposed to the client. This means that the agent does not include these in client reports. 

I want to trigger a message whenever a fact value equals something, and then have puppet sent this message in a report that Foreman is parsing for monitoring.

Comment: Removed that part, might be interesting how to bring those Puppet master warnings to Foreman, since they are not connected to the report in any way